# Use java stream to group by 2 keys on the same type

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Using java stream, how to create a Map from a List to index by 2 keys on the same class?

I give here a code Example, I would like the map "personByName" to get all person by firstName OR lastName, so I would like to get the 3 "steves": when it's their firstName or lastname. I don't know how to mix the 2 Collectors.groupingBy.

```
public static class Person {
    final String firstName;
    final String lastName;

    protected Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

}

@Test
public void testStream() {
    List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
            new Person("Bill", "Gates"),
            new Person("Bill", "Steve"),
            new Person("Steve", "Jobs"),
            new Person("Steve", "Wozniac"));

    Map<String, Set<Person>> personByFirstName = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getFirstName, Collectors.toSet()));
    Map<String, Set<Person>> personByLastName = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getLastName, Collectors.toSet()));

    Map<String, Set<Person>> personByName = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getLastName, Collectors.toSet()));// This is wrong, I want bot first and last name

    Assert.assertEquals("we should search by firstName AND lastName", 3, personByName.get("Steve").size()); // This fails

}
```

I found a workaround by looping on the 2 maps, but it is not stream-oriented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could merge the two `Map<String, Set<Person>>` for example

```
Map<String, Set<Person>> personByFirstName = 
                            persons.stream()
                                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                                   Person::getFirstName, 
                                                   Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new))
                                           );

persons.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getLastName, Collectors.toSet()))
       .forEach((str, set) -> personByFirstName.merge(str, set, (s1, s2) -> { 
            s1.addAll(s2); 
            return s1;
        }));

// personByFirstName contains now all personByName
```

Comment: Good and simple answer, I add to edit it a little bit to make it compile, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @pdem Glad it could help, it's true that it's more readable, but I think Andreas' answer will allow better performance, but I'm not sure if it's something you want/need and don't know if it's true

Comment: Be aware that [`Collectors.toSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--) provides "no guarantees on the mutability of the Set returned", so `s1.addAll(s2)` *may* throw `UnsupportedOperationException` (or similar) if the returned set is immutable. Even if it works now, it's a bomb waiting to go off in the future, if `toSet()` is changed. --- To fix, change first `toSet()` to `toCollection(HashSet::new)`, as suggested in the javadoc of `toSet()`.

Comment: @Andreas thanks I corrected it, it's always good to know! But I think this would be the problem with any use of toSet()

Answer (score 7):

You can do it like this:

```
Map<String, Set<Person>> personByName = persons.stream()
       .flatMap(p -> Stream.of(new SimpleEntry<>(p.getFirstName(), p),
                               new SimpleEntry<>(p.getLastName(), p)))
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SimpleEntry::getKey,
                   Collectors.mapping(SimpleEntry::getValue, Collectors.toSet())));
```

Assuming you add a `toString()` method to the `Person` class, you can then see result using:

```
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
        new Person("Bill", "Gates"),
        new Person("Bill", "Steve"),
        new Person("Steve", "Jobs"),
        new Person("Steve", "Wozniac"));

// code above here

personByName.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
Steve=[Steve Wozniac, Bill Steve, Steve Jobs]
Jobs=[Steve Jobs]
Bill=[Bill Steve, Bill Gates]
Wozniac=[Steve Wozniac]
Gates=[Bill Gates]
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be by using the newest JDK12's [`Collector.teeing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)):

```
Map<String, List<Person>> result = persons.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getFirstName, 
                                      Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)),
                Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getLastName),
                (byFirst, byLast) -> { 
                    byLast.forEach((last, peopleList) -> 
                           byFirst.computeIfAbsent(last, k -> new ArrayList<>())
                                  .addAll(peopleList));
                    return byFirst; 
                }));
```

`Collectors.teeing` collects to two separate collectors and then merges the results into a final value. From the docs:

> Returns a Collector that is a composite of two downstream collectors. Every element passed to the resulting collector is processed by both downstream collectors, then their results are merged using the specified merge function into the final result.

So, the above code collects to a map by first name and also to a map by last name and then merges both maps into a final map by iterating the `byLast` map and merging each one of its entries into the `byFirst` map by means of the [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) method. Finally, the `byFirst` map is returned.

Note that I've collected to a `Map<String, List<Person>>` instead of to a `Map<String, Set<Person>>` to keep the example simple. If you actually need a map of sets, you could do it as follows:

```
Map<String, Set<Person>> result = persons.stream().
       .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getFirstName, 
                                      Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)),
                Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getLastName, Collectors.toSet()),
                (byFirst, byLast) -> { 
                    byLast.forEach((last, peopleSet) -> 
                           byFirst.computeIfAbsent(last, k -> new LinkedHashSet<>())
                                  .addAll(peopleSet));
                    return byFirst; 
                }));
```

Keep in mind that if you need to have `Set<Person>` as the values of the maps, the `Person` class must implement the `hashCode` and `equals` methods *consistently*.

Comment: This is a very nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a real stream-oriented solution, make sure you don't produce any large intermediate collections, else most of the sense of streams is lost.

If just you want to just filter all Steves, filter first, collect later:

```java
persons.stream
  .filter(p -> p.getFirstName().equals('Steve') || p.getLastName.equals('Steve'))
  .collect(toList());
```

If you want to do complex things with a stream element, e.g. put an element into multiple collections, or in a map under several keys, just consume a stream using `forEach`, and write inside it whatever handling logic you want.

Comment: I will have thousands of gets on a static data, for only one Map construction. A Map access is O(1) and a filter access is O(n). I can accept that the index constuction is O(n.ln(n)) or O(n²). a filter is not the solution for my case, I could have precised it in the question.

Comment: Then just build maps and use them, it makes total sense! You don't need the stream mechanics which has a very different set of trade-offs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot key your maps by multiple values. For what you want to achieve, you have three options:

1. Combine your "personByFirstName" and "personByLastName" maps, you will have duplicate values (eg. Bill Gates will be in the map under the key `Bill` and also in the map under the key `Gates`). @Andreas answer gives a good stream-based way to do this.
2. Use an indexing library like lucene and index all your Person objects by first name and last name.
3. The stream approach - it will not be performant on large data sets but you can stream your collection and use `filter` to get your matches:

> ```
> persons
>     .stream()
>     .filter(p -> p.getFirstName().equals("Steve") 
>          || p.getLastName().equals("Steve"))
>     .collect(Collectors.asList());
> ```
>
> (I've written the syntax from memory so you might have to tweak it).

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you want to map each Person twice, once for the first name and once for the last.
To do this you have to double your stream somehow. Assuming Couple is some existing 2-tuple (Guava or Vavr have some nice implementation) you could:

```
persons.stream()
    .map(p -> new Couple(new Couple(p.firstName, p), new Couple(p.lastName, p)))
    .flatMap(c -> Stream.of(c.left, c.right)) // Stream of Couple(String, Person)
    .map(c -> new Couple(c.left, Arrays.asList(c.right)))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Couple::getLeft, Couple::getRight, Collection::addAll));
```

I didn't test it, but the concept is: make a stream of (name, person), (surname, person)... for every person, then simply map for the left value of each couple. The asList is to have a collection as value. If you need a Set chenge the last line with `.collect(Collectors.toMap(Couple::getLeft, c -> new HashSet(c.getRight), Collection::addAll))`

Answer (score 0):

Try `SetMultimap`, either from [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) or my library [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
SetMultimap<String, Person> result = Multimaps.newSetMultimap(new HashMap<>(), () -> new HashSet<>()); // by Google Guava.
// Or result = N.newSetMultimap(); // By Abacus-Util
persons.forEach(p -> {
     result.put(p.getFirstName(), p);
     result.put(p.getLastName(), p);
  });
```